# Drag and drop tabs in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Since Eclipse 3.7 (included) seems that the function of drag and drop editor tabs between eclipse windows has been removed (now the tab is disattached from the windows and its open in a new small window)

Is there any way to recover the previous behaviour?

Comment: I have 3.7 and it works for me. Are you sure you don't have configured something?

Comment: Yes, I did not explain it correctly. In 3.7 works but the feature is lost in later versions

Comment: I have tried it in Juno and it works as well

Comment: I can reproduce this in Kepler (the key word is "window"). Apparently works as designed, though: You can drag the windowed tab back to the original window, but not to another window. You should check the Eclipse bug tracker, and report the bug if it is not there. It does not belong here.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a possible regression bug that should be reported to the developers of the software.